# Trying to install GHUnit

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I have followed the instruction for installing GHUnit, and when i try to build i get the errors on the attached pic.[image]

Any ideas on what i have done wrong/missed?

Comment: I don't know too much about xcode or objective-c, but when we were working with C++ we had a similar issue when something was missing from the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If you have something like LD_LIBRARY_PATH in objective-c, try to add the AppKit to it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your prefix header. Double-click on your target to bring up the Target Info window and choose the Build tab. Check that the relevant Configuration is selected (Debug or All Configurations). Now type 'prefix' in the search box to view the relevant setting. 'Precompile Prefix Header' should be checked and 'Prefix Header' should be set to either

> $(SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/AppKit.h

or the name of the prefix header that you wish to use: MyTest_Prefix.pch or whatever you want to call it. The **first** entry in that .pch file should be

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

or

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
```

( imports  so you don't need both). While you're at it, add

```
#import <GHUnit/GHUnit.h>
```

and you don't need to keep repeating that either. I generally import my files with constant declarations, enumerations and categories in the prefix as well.